# ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient.HttpLog is not populating

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm having trouble enabling logging for a `ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient`.  I'm working from the documentation [Capture HTTP Headers in .NET Service Clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client.html#capture-http-headers-in-net-service-clients) but I must be missing something becasue I'm only ever getting an empty `string`.

Here's my code:

```
public class Client
{
    private bool Logging { get; }
    
    public Client(bool logging = false)
    {
        Api = new("https://api.service.com/");
        Logging = logging;
        if (Logging) Api.CaptureHttp(true, true);
    }

    public string GetInfo(string name)
    {
        if (Logging) Api.HttpLog.Clear();
        var response = Api.Get(new Requests.GetInfo(name));
        Debug.WriteLine(Api.HttpLog.ToString());
        return response.Result;
    }
}

[Route("/v1/getinfo/{name}")]
[DataContract]
public class GetInfo : Base, IReturn<Responses.GetInfo>
{
    public GetInfo(string name) => Name = name;

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; init; }
}


[TestMethod]
public void Client_GetInfo()
{
    var client = new Client(true);
    client.GetInfo()
}
```

Because I have `Api.CaptureHttp(true, true)` it is logging the info to the test log but I want to be able to capture the httpLog in code and like I said, it's only ever an empty `string` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CaptureHttp` has 3 flags:

```cs
public void CaptureHttp(bool print = false, bool log = false, bool clear = true)
```

You're only setting `Api.CaptureHttp(print:true,log:true)` which should print to the console and log to your logger if `IsDebugEnabled`, your call only sets the first 2 flags but you're code is relying on capturing the log to print it out in which case you wanted to specify that it shouldn't clear the HttpLog after each request with:

```cs
Api.CaptureHttp(clear:false)
```